# Struggling with an IN oracle query

Tags: sql, oracle

This is what my code looks like right now.

```
SELECT TITTEL, ISBN
FROM book b, subject s
WHERE b.ISBN = s.BOK AND s.sub IN('Database','Programming') ORDER BY b.year DESC;
```

With this query I find every book(bok) with the subject Database or Programming.

```
Kong Olav   123
Baser og enda mer baser 333
Baser og enda mer baser 333
```

But I want to find the books that have BOTH database and programming as its subject. How can I do this?

Comment: add `GROUP BY TITTEL, ISBN HAVING COUNT(*) = 2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close.  You can now use aggregation:

```
SELECT TITTEL, ISBN
FROM book b JOIN
     subject s
     ON b.ISBN = s.BOK 
WHERE s.sub IN ('Database', 'Programming')
GROUP BY TITTEL, ISBN
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT s.sub) = 2
ORDER BY MAX(YEAR) DESC;
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Very impressed that you understood what I was looking for.